# CIL: What does the "class" keyword mean when assigned to a ".field"?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I have a field definition:

```
.field public static initonly class A.Program/'<>c' '<>9'
```

This is part of a nested type generated by the C# compiler. I would like to construct something similar using ILGenerator.Emit.

- I have attempted to view the C# in ILSpy, but it hides the nested
  type ("Nested Types") for me.
- I haven't found anything in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf).

Using ILDasm/ILasm, I built the following code in the hope it would give me the C#:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly Test
{

  // --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
  //  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 00 03 01 00 00 00 00 ) 

  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.module Test
// MVID: {9110E73E-F37F-4E22-9D43-20F26D4A4C8F}

// --- The following custom attribute is added automatically, do not uncomment -------
//  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = ( 01 00 03 01 00 00 00 00 ) 

.imagebase 0x00400000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x0000029D41150000


// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class private auto ansi Test
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .field public static initonly class System.Object 'x'

} // end of class Test


// =============================================================

// *********** DISASSEMBLY COMPLETE ***********************
```

with

```
ilasm /dll /debug test.il
```

ILSpy translates my `.field public static initonly class System.Object 'x'` line to `.field public static initonly object x` (omitting the `class` keyword and resulting in `public static readonly object x;` C#)

Comment: Where do you got your field definition from?

Comment: it's part of the code .NET generates for e.g.Task.Run(() => { Console.WriteLine("hello world");  });

Comment: `class` here is syntactically part of the name `class A.Program/'<>c'`. See section  II.23.2.12. `.field public static initonly class A.Program/'<>c' '<>9'` is equivalent to `public static readonly A.Program.<>c <>9` (i.e. a field named `<>9` of the type `<>c` which is a nested type of `A.Program`), except of course that these are not valid identifiers in C#. To see this in ILSpy, select either "IL" or "IL with C#" as its output type; by default these types are transparently translated back into idiomatic C#.

Comment: thank you @JeroenMostert! If you were to write that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: I suppose you were a bit unlucky, [object] is a keyword in IL.  So doesn't require the class annotation that types normally get.  Reflection.Emit doesn't have the code rewriting logic that the C# compiler uses to translate lambdas, async, iterators, etc.  The kind that generates hidden types with the wonky angle brackets, you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Per ECMA-335:

> *Field* `::= .field` *FieldDecl*
>
> *FieldDecl* `::=` [ `‘[’` Int32 `‘]’` ] *FieldAttr*`*` *Type* *Id* [ `‘=’`*FieldInit* `| at` *DataLabel* ]
>
> *FieldAttr* `::=` `assembly` | `famandassem` | `family` | `famorassem` | `initonly` | `literal` | `marshal` `‘(’` *NativeType* `‘)’` | `notserialized` | `private` | `compilercontrolled` | `public` | `rtspecialname` | `specialname` | `static`
>   *Type* `::=` `‘!’` *Int32* | `‘!!’` *Int32* | `bool` | `char` | `class` *TypeReference* | `float32` | `float64` | `int8` | `int16` | `int32` | `int64` | `method` *CallConv* *Type* `‘*’` `‘(’` *Parameters* `‘)’` | `native int` | `native unsigned int` | `object` | `string` | *Type* `‘&’` | *Type* `‘*’` | *Type* `‘<’` *GenArgs* `‘>’` | *Type* `‘[’` [ *Bound* [ `‘,’` *Bound* ] `*` ] `‘]’` | *Type* `modopt` `‘(’` *TypeReference* `‘)’` | *Type* `modreq` `‘(’` *TypeReference* `‘)’` | *Type*
>   `pinned` | `typedref` | `valuetype` *TypeReference* | `unsigned int8` | `unsigned int16` | `unsigned int32` | `unsigned int64` | `void`
>
> *TypeSpec* `::=` `‘[’` [ `.module` ] *DottedName* `‘]’` | *TypeReference* | *Type*

As you can see, `class` is not a part of the field declaration, but of the type itself (*TypeSpec* can be used in other places where `class` or `valuetype` can be omitted). I am not 100 % sure why `class` or `valuetype` must be used in some cases, but there is also `boxed` *TypeReference*, so possibly originally, a form of the type could have been chosen as well.